# Need to insert breaks in strings of very column with ' ' or ','

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has one Column but over 100,000 rows
             Col_Name
             qwchijhuirhxnihdiuyfnx

```
         dhjhfiurhncnmxmzjcoinrds

         xnbxknsiiuncirnxknrxnxz
```

I need to insert a '.' or '$' or some marker after every 3rd character

Example of result needed:

```
         Col_Name
         qwc.hij.hui.rhx.nih.diu.yfn.x
         dhj.hfi.urh.ncn.mxm.zjc.oin.rds.
         xnb.xkn.sii.unc.irn.xkn.rxn.xz
```

I originally solved this with:

```
INSERT INTO New_Table
(
c1
,c2
,c3
)
SELECT 
     substring(CAST(Col_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)),1,3) as C1
     ,substring(CAST(Col_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)),4,3) as C2
     ,substring(CAST(Col_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)),7,3) as C3
     From Table_Name
```

---

This causes problems later in the script so the data must remain in one column but could be inserted into a new table as long as it was a new table with just one column

Comment: What is the min and max length of the column text before tranformation?  Can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example of your table & data?

Comment: the column is varchar max min is (3) some rows could hold 10,000 characters. Not good but its what Ive been given to work with.

Comment: Is it a one-off transformation or does it need to run efficiently?

Comment: run efficiently, because it is applied to millions of rows

Comment: And thank you Andy for looking at this

Comment: It is probably faster to write a function with a while loop if it only runs once in 30 minutes, than to spend hours writing and profiling different query techniques :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sqlfiddle starting point you can refactor http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab6dd/1/0 using function and while loop.

You may be able to do something more efficient with regular expressions or SQLCLR if you need speed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dotify (@input varchar(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @output varchar(MAX) = ''

declare @index int = 0
declare @length int
set @length = len(@input)
while @index <= @length
begin
 SET @output = @output + substring(@input, @index, 1)
 if (@index % 3) = 0 AND @index > 0
 BEGIN
   SET @output = @output +'.'
 END
 set @index = @index + 1
end
return(@output)
END
GO
select TOP 10000 col_name, dbo.dotify(col_name) FROM  old_table
```

You can use TOP to limit the processing time to a few seconds so you can easily profile efficiency changes you make.

Comment: Thank you it does exactly what I need Andy